# How to create a redirect page in Google Sites?

Tags: google, redirects, page

How to create a redirect page in Google Sites?

Example: Home → Page → *redirect*

Comment: Please ensure you check for duplicates before posting... there is a lot of redirection type questions for Google Apps and Google sites already on Pro Webmasters, also just to add if you did look but can't find one that is in the format you'd like then this wouldn't justify making a new question, its just because no one has left a great answer and this is the voting system is so effective on the Stack Exchange because questions and answers improve over time. Thx.